# What does "in the two previous years" imply?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> Yet Amazon’s shareholders are working on the premise that it is just getting started. Since the beginning of 2015 its share price has jumped by 173%, seven times quicker than **in the two previous years** (and 12 times faster than the S&P 500 index).

Does it mean it is growing seven times quicker from 2015 to 2017 than from 2013 to 2015?

http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21719487-amazon-has-potential-meet-expectations-investors-success-will-bring-big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yah they are talking  about the range between 2013 and 2015.